# Swift 4 migration getting error Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]?' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'

Tags: migration, ios11, swift4

```
let linkTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue as Int),
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: FAColor.blackColor()
      ]

self.lblPinDidNotMatchDescription.linkTextAttributes = linkTextAttributes
```

Getting error on Swift 4 migration

> "Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]?' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'".

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Change to `NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue`

Example

```
let linkTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]  = [
                    NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
                    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
                ]
```